# Removing null bytes from shell code

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am learning the basics of shell coding so that I can learn to exploit buffer overflows. The problem is, the example byte code that I wrote contains null bytes. Here is the example:

```
xor    %edi,%edi      >       31 ff         
mov    $0x3c,%eax     >       b8 3c 00 00 00          
syscall               >       0f 05
```

Bytecode : `"\x31\xff\xb8\x3c\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x05"`

What are some common techniques used to eliminate null bytes? I heard that people use encoders for this sort of thing but I cannot find any great resources on this.

Comment: https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/msfencode/

Comment: @paj28 [msfvenom](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/msfvenom/) will replace both msfpayload and msfencode as of June 8th, 2015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mov` can be replaced by `push` and `pop`. So eg this:

```
mov    $0x3c,%eax
```

Can become this:

```
push $0x3c
pop %eax
```

Which would give you this null byte free code:

```
   0:   31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
   2:   6a 3c                   push   $0x3c
   4:   58                      pop    %eax
   5:   0f 05                   syscall
```

Comment: you can also use the lowest register: `mov 0x3c, %al`